# Converting dynamic 2D arrays into Mat with openCV in C++ (grayscale)

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, visual-studio-2017, grayscale

I need to convert 2D dynamic array into Mat and save it as a new grayscale image
this is my code (keeps crashing after converting the array into Mat):

```
    #define N 4000
    #define M 3500

    int **Bitplane = new int *[N];

    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
        {
    Bitplane[i] = new int[M];
        }
    //processing and filling the matrix ...etc


    Mat BPimage(704, 1280, CV_64F, Bitplane);//crashing with dynamic arrays
    imwrite("//location and name.jpg//", BPimage);

    puts("OK");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
    delete[] Bitplane[i];
    }

    delete[] Bitplane;
```

Comment: Is it M or N ? and Its better to define colsnumber and rowsnumber too. This is not crashing in my environment. What is the program output message?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I have edited the code .. it's not showing any messages just "Press any key to continue...", not even passing that phase to display "OK" message

Comment: This is not supported, the data needs to be a linear array. You're telling the `Mat` constructor that `Bitplane` is an array of 704*1280 64bit floats -- it's not, hence the crash.

Comment: Its writing the image correctly and also showing the OK message, there is no prblem with me. @DanMašek Why not crashing at me?

Comment: This `CV_64F` means `double`, so why are you using `int` ? `cv::Mat` takes `void*` to one contiguous area of memory, `double* data = new double[704 * 1280]`.